# declare dynamic array in function

Tags: c++, arrays

in which cases should I use the keyword **new** to allocate array when the size is a variable? I am reading this code: https://github.com/Hawstein/cracking-the-coding-interview/blob/master/1.7.cpp

In the function **zero()**, why **row[m]** and **col[n]** declarations doesn't cause errors? The **m** and **n** are function variables.

Thanks

Comment: Never, use `std::vector`.

Comment: @40two , i am sorry?

Comment: That's a C++ extension, VLAs are C stuff

Comment: variable-length arrays are nonstandard extension in C++. => use new instead.

Comment: C++ doesn't support variable length arrays. Consequently, you should never use them neither you should use `new`. Use a `std::vector` if you want a variable sized dynamic array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21519062/1938163) - variable length arrays are a nonstandard extension of the C++ language, thus your code can only be compiled [with a compiler extension](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8404cb347bf35e79)

You should use dynamic allocated memory in every case when you don't know in advance the size of the array and you don't want/can't waste precious stack memory allocating a temporary or, even better if that works for you, use a `std::vector` (a vector uses heap memory anyway for its elements)

Edit: Another important suggestion is to take a look at [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) which can often offer additional advantages over raw pointers

Comment: I have one more question. if I new something within a function and return its pointer. Is the returned pointer a ghost one? Is something created by new, will only be freed by the keyword delete? Thanks

Comment: I recommend a smart pointer for such operations since it frees you from the hassle of having to free memory when it goes out of scope (plus other advantages). Anyway, yes: the book-keeping is your duty with `new`

Answer (score 0):

Never.

Modern c++ compilers can handle variables for array sizes.  They just use the values currently in `m` and `n`.  There is no need to use `new`.

Comment: The only time you need to use `new` is if you need to have a variable whose scope is not local.  In other words, only if you need to either 1) delete the variable before the function exits or 2) keep the variable around after the function exits.

Comment: Just because some compilers can handle them (without certain flags that people like me use during compilation) doesn't make them portable or standard.